# Can you say "get on the rear of the bus"?

Tags: sentence-construction

There is someone getting on the bus and taking a seat in the rear of the bus. When you are describing this person, I think you can use this sentence:

> He got on the bus in a seat in the rear of the bus.

To make it simpler, is it possible to use this sentence instead?

> He got on the rear of the bus.

I'm not certain if you must keep "get on the bus" part together as in the first sentence, or you can split up "get on" and "the bus" as in the second sentence.

Comment: _He got on the bus and found/went to a seat in the rear._ If you say _he got on the rear_ it sounds as though he climbed directly on to the back of the vehicle. Speaking from my own experience in the UK, when buses used to have both a driver and a conductor (who collected the fares), the passenger door _was_ often at the rear, but now that the driver takes the fares the door is always at the front.

Comment: I would phrase this either as 'He got on and sat at the back of the bus.' or 'He got on the bus and sat at the back.'

Comment: @KateBunting I seem to be commenting on a lot of questions just after you do. I see you are in the UK; I am commenting from point of view of a USA (West coast) English speaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Get on the rear" would mean, getting on using the entrance at the back of the bus (on the old London busses, this was the normal entrance)

In your situation you mean "He sat at the rear of the bus" (if it doesn't matter which door he used to get on).  Many conductor-less buses only let people on at the front.

Comment: Even more modern buses that use contactless passcards now let people board at both the front and the rear (i.e., there are card readers at both doors), at least where I live.